# how to send WPF DataGrid row to bottom of DataGrid depending on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have datagrid on window. I want to send specific row at the bottom of grid depending on condition in code.
For ex:

```
if(!Row.Isenable)
{
///send this row to bottom of grid
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: How do you set the datsource of the grid ? what is the source ? list or databale etc ?

Comment: Please go through this MSDN library .. May be it will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx

Comment: @AccessDenied data source is list object. but it doesn't matter i think. because i am using everything from UI. and i want to work on UI. i don't want to changes source

Comment: jagatap : this will help me but i have to go through each and every function. but i want to know exact property to change row position.